# Linear gradient-like design where color 2 is in the center and color 1 is off to the sides

Tags: css

Sorry if the title doesn't describe it well, but what I'm looking to do is mimic the following design.

[image]

Let's say I'm using `#1A6592` as the blueish color. Is it possible to make it fade to white in the center? I've looked at different linear gradient generators such as http://ie.microsoft.com/Testdrive/Graphics/CSSGradientBackgroundMaker/Default.html and can't see a way they have of doing that, so I'm not sure if it's possible or not using CSS.

Here's a fiddle for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9vLdLcn2/

Comment: Use one like this: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 1):

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1a6592 0%,#ffffff 50%,#1a6592 100%);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only `linear` and `radial` gradients are possible in CSS at this point, so the way to achieve this would be to have three input colors with the two outermost ones being the same and the middle one white. Here's an example for you:

```css
.faded-blue-background { 
    background: #2989d8;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #2989d8 0%, #7db9e8 50%, #2989d8 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#2989d8), color-stop(50%,#7db9e8), color-stop(100%,#2989d8));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #2989d8 0%,#7db9e8 50%,#2989d8 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #2989d8 0%,#7db9e8 50%,#2989d8 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #2989d8 0%,#7db9e8 50%,#2989d8 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #2989d8 0%,#7db9e8 50%,#2989d8 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2989d8', endColorstr='#2989d8',GradientType=1 );
    padding: 20px;
}
.faded-blue-background h3, .faded-blue-background li { color: #FFF; }
```

```html
<div class="faded-blue-background">
    <h3>Here's a div</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Here's a list item</li> 
        <li>Here's a list item</li>
        <li>Here's a list item</li>
        <li>Here's a list item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

(the gradient was generated with the [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/))